# useForm in react is not working properly for two manual update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React.
I was using a hook as instructed by Ben Awad in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xhKH43llhU&list=PLN3n1USn4xlmyw3ebYuZmGp60mcENitdM&index=1). The code of my useForm hook is as follows.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export const useForm = initialValues => {
  const [values, changeValue] = useState(initialValues);
  const func = e => {
    changeValue({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  return [values, func];
};
```

It was working perfect but I faced one issue when I have to manually update the state. I declared the state as follows.

```
 const [inputs, changeInputs] = useForm({ name:'', email: '', password: '', mobile: '' });
```

and changing the values in the input tag as below (It was also working good):-

```
<input onChange={changeInputs} type="email" name="email" value={inputs.email} placeholder="Enter E-mail address" />
```

When I was updating only one value of the state manually inside a function, it was working fine (The code is below)

```
const handleRegister = event => {
  event.prevenDefault();
  changeInputs({ target: { name: 'mobile', value: '1111111111' } });
  //changeInputs({ target: { name: 'name', value: 'Anuj' } });
}
```

But when I uncomment the 4th line of the above code, only **name** was updating the mobile value is the same as the default.

**Edit1**- **Code of** *func = (e) =>*

```
const func = (e) => {
 changeValue(values => { return { ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }});
 // changeValue({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
```

**EDIT2 - Solution(Static Solution)**
Just change the useForm as below

```
import { useState } from 'react';

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export const useForm = initialValues => {
 const [values, changeValue] = useState(initialValues);
 const func = (e) => {
  console.log(e.type);
  if(e.type==='change')
   changeValue({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  else
   changeValue(state => { return { ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }});
 };
return [values, func];
};
```

**EDIT3 - Simple & Sweet Solution**
Visit [this for the solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bogdan-494zc)  by [HermitCrab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6476889/hermitcrab)  or just change the *func* function as below.

```
 const func = (e) => {
  const {name,value} = e.target;
  changeValue(state => { return { ...state, [name]: value }});
 };
```

Comment: I'm not very experienced with React Hooks yet, but it seems that this one is fundamentally not designed to be used twice, as you are doing. The problem is that `values` will always be the value returned from `useState`, which won't "see" the new value from the first `changeInputs` call. I'm afraid I don see straight away how to alter `useForm` so that this works, but I expect we will have developers here who will.

Comment: To put it another way, I think this is only designed to be used as an `onChange` method. Calling it twice in a row, manually, is what causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`changeValue` is asynchronous, so when your call `changeInputs` twice in a row, this is what's happening:

```
// 1st call: values is { name:'', email: '', password: '', mobile: '' }
changeValue({ ...values, mobile: '1111111111' });

// 2nd call: values still is { name:'', email: '', password: '', mobile: '' }
changeValue({ ...values, name: 'Anuj' });
```

So only the second call will be saved:

```
values: { name: 'Anuj', email: '', password: '', mobile: '' }
```

To fix that problem, you need to modify `useForm.changeValue`:

```
const { name, value } = e.target;
changeValue(state => { return { ...state, [name]: value }});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Can you please elaborate on what I have to do? Do I have to change the useForm.js or something else?

Comment: Just change the `changeValue` in your `useForm`, see the last line of my answer

Comment: `import { useState } from 'react';

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export const useForm = initialValues => {
  const [values, changeValue] = useState(initialValues);
  const func =(e) => {
    changeValue(values => { return { ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }});
  };
  return [values, func];
};`
I hope, I changed the same line as you are directing but it is giving error as *e* is not defined in changeValue.

Comment: It is showing error...
**Line 7:50:  Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals**

_Line 7 is_  `    changeValue(values => { return { ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }});`

Comment: My bad, use `e`. I was confused because you use `e` in `useForm ` and `event` in `handleRegister`

Comment: `e` is defined here: `func =(e) => ...`

Comment: I got the same error as I was getting earlier. **TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null** on same line.

Comment: Could you add `console.log(e.target)` inside `const func = e => {` just before `changeValue`

Comment: Oh!! Sorry the given modification is working for manual updation but not for the synthetic event (changing values from input tag) It is giving type error.... **TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null**.

The output for the synthetic event by console.log is `<input placeholder="Your Good Name" type="text" name="name" value="A">`

Comment: Sure, I have edited my post. You can get the code below **EDIT1**

Comment: In this code, you cannot reuse the name `values` because it has already be defined, just replace `values` with `state` (or any name you want but not `values`). Regarding e.target.name, it is defined according to your console.log so I don't understand.

Comment: **Cannot read property 'name' of null** means that `e.target` is `null`. But if you console.log(e.target) and you get something like `<input...`, it means that e.target is not null. So it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hey, Can't we put some `if else` condition for synthetic and manual events?

Comment: Hey, It worked finally. I just put an `if else` condition for `event.type`.

Comment: Thank You for your time. You saved my night!! **PS- To overcome the issue You have to update the useForm.js. Just see under _EDIT 2_**

Comment: There is another way, in your func: add `const {name, value} = e.target;` then `changeValue(state => { return { ...state, [name]: value }});`

Comment: I created a sandbox with that solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bogdan-494zc

Comment: Hey. Could you please help me to understand why your initial code is not working?

Comment: `changeValue` is asynchronous. So when you call `changeValue`, it is not executed immediately but a bit later. Meanwhile, React will recycle the event for performance reasons. So by the time `changeValue` is really executed, the event is gone and you cannot reference it anymore. To fix that problem, you can make a copy of name and value `const {name, value} = e.target;` and use them later safely